# How add getters to all objects

Tags: javascript, getter-setter

How can I add getters (or prototype/method) to all object.
I have an object that look like:

```
foo.bar.text
//or
foo.bar.child.text
```

`text` - is an array of strings, but I need only one of them.
Each time when I get this value, I want get only one fixed index (this index saved in other variable).

So what I need in result:

```
foo.text = ['a','b'] 
foo.bar.text = ['c','d']
foo.bar.someChild.text = [null, undefined]
x = 1;

// here we make some magic

console.log(foo.text) // b
console.log(foo.bar.text) // d
console.log(foo.bar.someChild.text) // undefined
```

So if any object contains an array `text`, if we try get it, we get not array but some defined item from it.

Manually point on item I can't so `foo.bar.text[x]` is not an option.
Name of array and variable that we get is optional, for example we can save array in `fullText` and try get `text`. As if `text = fullText[x]`.

Can somebody advice how I can implement this, getter, setter, prototype?

**Update**
Proxy seems is my option, thanks for advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you apply [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) recursively to the `foo` object.

```
// the code is handwriting without test
var handler = {
  get: (target, prop) => {
    if (prop === 'text') {
       if (target[prop] instanceof Array) {
         return target[prop][x];
       } else {
         // dealing with non-array value
       }
    } else if (typeof target[prop] === 'object') {
       return new Proxy(target[prop], handler);
    } else {
       return target[prop];
    }
  }
}
var newFoo = new Proxy(foo, handler);
```

Comment: Note: `typeof target[prop]` will be equal to `"object"` if `target[prop]` is an array.